# Notes in CRM2013 Online changes timestamps when record is reassigned - can I change this?

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Whenever we assign an Account to a different owner in CRM2013 Online, the timestamps for the notes change, to match the time the account was assigned and who assigned the account. Is it possible to change this, so the timestamp only shows, when the note was created? And show who originally created the note?

I see the logic in the way is works now. It updates to show when it was last changed and who changed it - but I would LOVE to change it, so it would show WHO created the note and WHEN it was created.
Is this a thing you can change in the current iteration of CRM2013?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it would be possible. But anyway try to leave your suggestion on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions).

Answer (score 0):

It's an impact of the Cascade for Assign action on Account.
You can switch off that Cascading from the relationship between Account and Note.

However it's necessary to check if new owner has access to related Notes accordingly to his role permissions.